# liferay CK editor value lost after rerender

Tags: editor, ckeditor, liferay, taglib, icefaces-3

This is my code, just simple test with 1 `<liferay-ui:input-editor />` and 1 button that call to server and swich [render] value (true [render as default] - false)
first time I load this CK it show my value [this is .....], click on [test it] button and then, click it again to rerender CK editor, my value is gone !? can anyone show me why please!
I had tried, set [render] = false as default, when click on button, CK render with my value, but not on second times it rerender.
ps: liferay 6.1 ga 1 and icefaces 3

```
  <h:form id="test">
       <ice:panelGroup rendered="#{CchcDmFeedbackController.render == true}">
           <liferay-ui:input-editor toolbarSet="editInPlace" value="this is my test text value"/>
       </ice:panelGroup>
       <ice:commandButton value="test it" actionListener="#{CchcDmFeedbackController.actionTest}"/>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: try to change h:form to ice:form, there is no use :(

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following isssue:

http://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1422
liferay-ui:input-editor causes invalid DOM diff during Ajax postback when used with ICEfaces

The fix for this will appear in the next version. For now, you can try the SNAPSHOT version from the [snapshot repository](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/liferay/faces/).

Now, it turns out that I found another similar problem just a few hours ago:

http://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-1435
p_p_auth URL parameter causing DOM diff inefficiency with ICEfaces

... and I'm actively working on a fix. Please click the "watch" link on the JIRA issue for updates.